# How to Implement Required Validation on Text Boxes in JQuery Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, popup

I have a JQuery Popup which includes some text boxes. I have applied Required validation on text boxes from Model but it doesn't work in popup. Without popup, validation works accurately.
Please help in this regard that is there any special syntax in JQuery popup for controls validations.Here is my popup code..

```
var dialogBox = $("#mc-dialog");
        $('#dvMCodes').on('click', '#tblMC .modalEdit', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            var actionURL = $(this).attr('href');

            //alert(actionURL);

            $(dialogBox).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Edit',
                modal: true,
                show: "blind",
                width: 'auto',
                hide: "blind",
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(actionURL, function (html) {
                        $('form', html).submit(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: this.action,
                                type: this.method,
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                success: function (res) {
                                    if (res.success) {
                                        $(dialogBox).dialog('close');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

            $(dialogBox).dialog('open');
        });
```

and here is my Model's code

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
```

and here is HTML Code

```
@if (IsEditMode)
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                }
                else   
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Code)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Code)
                }

            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description)
            </li>
```

Comment: Show some code please!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao look at now

Comment: Your html form code? Which validation library are you using?

Comment: Any backend code you are using??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao here is all the code

Comment: Try to add form validation condition **if($("form").valid())** before ajax call. if valid form allow ajax call

Comment: Here is demo fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/aGJrZ/9/

Comment: @GuruprasadRao  my solution is very costly can any one help ?

Comment: either use `formvalidation` jquery plugin or get `jquery-unobtrusive` validation js from `nuget` and try enable client side validation in MVC!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao can you provide some code for that ..from where can i get these?

Comment: **[FormValidation1](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)**,  **[Set of other plugins](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-form-validation-plugins/)**, **[Client side validation in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).submit(function (event) {

        if ($.trim($('#code').val()).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter value for Code');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: But this is a very costly solution can anyone help ?